# Which Magic Keyboard has this layout on the new Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have an external magic keyboard. I picked this model because it has the exact same layout as the keyboard of my current Macbook Pro 15" mid-2015.

I'm now going to upgrade to one of the just released Macbooks, and I want the keyboards (the external and internal keyboards) to have the exact same layout. Including the horizontal shape of the enter button, and the location of the `\` right on top of the enter button.

Which keyboard should I pick to get the layout? Is it the english US? does the enter button have the shape I need?

[image: keyboard layout]

Comment: People be looking for an enter button all day on that hardware :) apple is hard core on the return key with a physical enter only on extended layouts.

Comment: @bmike - I've often wondered about that. Having only ever owned extended keyboards, I wonder how you, for instance, exit a text box in Photoshop - which uses Return for new line & Enter for 'finish work', exit edit mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the layout called "US English" in the store, the ANSI [American standard] keyboard. Apple has an excellent explainer for rapidly identifying hardware keyboards:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794

The clues are…
The top left key is backtick & tilde  <kbd>`</kbd>   &  <kbd>~</kbd> 
The left shift is long & is immediately left of  <kbd>Z</kbd> 
The  <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd>  key is horizontal.

[image]

Contrast this with the layouts called "British English" or "International English" in stores, the ISO [European standard] keyboard…
The key top left is  <kbd>§</kbd>  &  <kbd>±</kbd> 
The left shift is short, allowing for an additional key, for  <kbd>`</kbd>   &  <kbd>~</kbd> 
The  <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd>  key is vertical & L-shaped. This also moves the  <kbd>| \</kbd>  key down a row.

[image]